# Java “String index out of range”

Tags: java, string

I wrote this function that would work prefectly but I got an exception:

> StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range:"String index out of range: (length of the string)"

This is the code:

```
private static String inverse(String a) {
    char[] invers = null;
    String f;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
        invers[i] = a.charAt(a.length() - (i - 1));
    }
    f = new String(invers);
    return (f);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String chaine = sc.nextLine();
    String ch = inverse(chaine);
    System.out.println("l'inv de" + args[0] + "est" + ch);
    if (!args[0].equals(ch))
        System.out.println(args[0] + "n'est pas palind");
    else
        System.out.println(args[0] + "est palind");
}
```

Comment: Step through the code with a debugger and take a look at the state of things (`a.length()`, `i`, `i-1`, etc.) when the exception is thrown.

Comment: Please don't evolve your question if you stumple into a new problem after the last one was answered here. You have to ask a new question for this.

Answer (score 2):

Replace this

`invers[i]=a.charAt(a.length()-(i-1))`

with

```
invers[i]=a.charAt(a.length()-i-1)
```

For `i = 0` you are trying to access the index at `a.length() + 1`, that is why you get the exception.

Also you need to initialize `invers`.

Use `char[] invers= new char[a.length()]` instead of `char[] invers = null`.

Here is the complete code:

```
private static String inverse(String a) {
    char[] invers = new char[a.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
        invers[i] = a.charAt(a.length() - i - 1);
    }
    String f = new String(invers);
    return f;
}
```

Comment: nothing :/ Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at ex3.Ex3.inverse(Ex3.java:21)
 at ex3.Ex3.main(Ex3.java:31)

Comment: you need to initialize the `invers` array. check the edit

Comment: i still got "String index out of range"

Answer (score 0):

You could do this...?

```
//convert original string to a array
char[] arr = a.toCharArray();
cha[] invers = new char[arr.length];

//reverse it
for(int i = (arr.length - 1); i <= 0; i--)
{
    inverse[arr.length - i] = a[i];
}
```

Comment: Well, he or she wouldn't be happy with it, because it wouldn't compile (`cha`) and because the loop body wouldn't be entered (check the termination condition).

Comment: told me array required but string found in this line: invers[arr.length - i] = a[i];

Answer (score 0):

2 problems in inverse() method :

```
private static String inverse(String a) {
    // array must get a size to get initialized
    // char[] invers = null;
    char[] invers = new char[a.length()];
    String f;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
        // INCORRECT :
        // invers[i] = a.charAt(a.length() - (i - 1));
        // CORRECT :
        invers[i] = a.charAt(a.length() - i - 1);
    }
    f = new String(invers);
    return (f);
}
```

Comment: i got another exception : java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Comment: thank you it's solved i got to change args[0] in main :D